# Mock method in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle, mockito, powermock

I'm newbie with Mockito.
I'm tring to mock this piece of code writed in Oracle ADF.

```
else {
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,                                                         new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
             "No Cases found in Queue",null));
        }
```

And this is my mock:

```
    FacesMessage facesMessageMock = mock(FacesMessage.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(FacesContext.class);
    PowerMockito.when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(facesContextMock);
```

But I have this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Are you using the required PrepareForTest and RunWith annotations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following annotations on your test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(FacesContext.class)
public class YourTest {
...
}
```

For details and example see [this page](http://goo.gl/aJxry).